# Copy Change of specific files use Github Action

Tags: shell, github, github-actions

I need to commit all changes in the repo to another repo. I was write this script but that did not change all the specific files I need will be changed only one file.
Anyone can help me to correct my script

```
    - name: Copy/Create file
      run: |
        FILE=./project1/test.php
        FILE2=./project1/test2.php
        if [ -f "$FILE" ]; 
        then
          echo "Copying $FILE"
          cp -R ./project1/test1.php ./project2
        elif [ -f "$FILE2" ]; 
        then
          echo "Copying $FILES"
          cp -R ./main-project/test2.php ./project2
        fi
     - name: Push change
       run: |
        cd ./project2
        git add .
        git config user.name "username"
        git config user.email “useremail”
        git checkout -b new-branch
        git commit -am "Commit Change"
        git push --set-upstream origin new-branch
```

Comment: You probably would like to commit changes in files, which already exist in another repo? Then consider to use the `git diff [<options>] --no-index [--] <path> <path> `. See more details in official documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt-emgitdiffemltoptionsgt--no-index--ltpathgtltpathgt

Comment: use git diff instead of using git push? Could you please write it for me

Comment: Use `diff` instead of coping files I mean. Are you trying to merge changes via using the command `cp`?

Comment: use "cp" to copy the content of files. After copy change "push" change it